# Applying a given markup to two consecutive syllables in lyrics

Tags: lilypond, lyrics, lily-scheme

Given the following LilyPond MWE:

```
melody = \relative c' {
  a( b) c
}

lyra = \lyricmode {
  Foo bar baz
}

lyrb = \lyricmode {
  Foo -- bar baz
}

lyrc = \lyricmode {
  Foo __ bar baz
}

\score {
  <<
    \new Voice = "melody" \melody
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" \lyra
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" \lyrb
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" \lyrc
  >>

  \layout {}
  \midi {}
}
```

How could I write a custom function that applies a given markup (e.g. bold or italic) to two consecutive syllables in lyrics? And how could I handle the `--` or `__` between syllables when applying this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is really what you want:

The syllables in `\lyricmode` are music events with the text as `text` property. The `--` and `__` things are parsed to articulations. So you can write a music function like this:

```
applyToTwoSyllables =
#(define-music-function (what syl1 syl2) (symbol? ly:music? ly:music?)
   (ly:music-set-property! syl1 'text
                           (primitive-eval
                            `(markup
                              ,(symbol->keyword what)
                              ,(ly:music-property syl1 'text))))
   (ly:music-set-property! syl2 'text
                           (primitive-eval
                            `(markup
                              ,(symbol->keyword what)
                              ,(ly:music-property syl2 'text))))
   #{ #syl1 #syl2 #})
```

which essentially takes the name of a markup function (e.g. `bold`) and two music objects and replaces the `text` property by essentially `(markup #:proc-name original-text)`. The `primitive-eval` stuff is only necessary so that the keyword arguments get evaluated correctly. If you create a function for say specifically making thing bold you can simply do

```
boldTwoSyllables =
#(define-music-function (syl1 syl2) (ly:music? ly:music?)
   (ly:music-set-property! syl1 'text
                           (markup #:bold (ly:music-property syl1 'text)))
   (ly:music-set-property! syl2 'text
                           (markup #:bold (ly:music-property syl2 'text)))
   #{ #syl1 #syl2 #})

lyra = \lyricmode {
  \boldTwoSyllables Foo bar baz
}
```

In any case you can now do

```
melody = \relative c' {
  a( b) c d
}

lyra = \lyricmode {
  \applyToTwoSyllables bold Foo bar baz
}

lyrb = \lyricmode {
  \applyToTwoSyllables italic Foo -- bar baz
}

lyrc = \lyricmode {
  Foo __ bar baz
}

\score {
  <<
    \new Voice = "melody" \melody
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" \lyra
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" \lyrb
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" \lyrc
  >>

  \layout {}
  \midi {}
}
```

EDIT:

You could also generalize this to an arbitrary number of syllables like this:

```
applyToLyrics =
#(define-music-function (what lyrics) (symbol? ly:music?)
   (define (iter mus)
     (let ((elt (ly:music-property mus 'element))
           (elts (ly:music-property mus 'elements))
           (text (ly:music-property mus 'text)))
       (if (music-is-of-type? mus 'lyric-event)
           (ly:music-set-property! mus 'text
                                   (primitive-eval
                                    `(markup
                                      ,(symbol->keyword what)
                                      ,text))))
       (if (not (null? elt))
           (ly:music-set-property! mus 'element (iter elt)))
       (ly:music-set-property! mus 'elements (map iter elts)))
     mus)
   (iter lyrics))

melody = \relative c' {
  a( b) c d
}

lyra = \lyricmode {
  \applyToLyrics bold { Foo bar } baz
}

lyrb = \lyricmode {
  \applyToLyrics italic Foo -- bar baz
}

lyrc = \lyricmode {
  \applyToLyrics box { Foo __ bar baz }
}

\score {
  <<
    \new Voice = "melody" \melody
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" \lyra
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" \lyrb
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "melody" \lyrc
  >>

  \layout {}
  \midi {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way: define a Scheme function that inserts the override and revert commands on either side of the lyrics.

This example sets lyrics in italics; to use it you would enclose the relevant lyrics in the command: `\EmphLyrics { ly -- rics }`.

```
\version "2.20"

EmphLyrics = 
#(define-scheme-function
  (text) (scheme?)
  #{
    \override Lyrics.LyricText.font-shape = #'italic
    $text
    \revert Lyrics.LyricText.font-shape
  #})

{
    c'8 c'8 d'8 d'8 e'8 e'8 f'8 f'8 g'8 g'8 g'4
}
\addlyrics {
    al -- pha be -- ta \EmphLyrics { gam -- ma del -- ta } ep -- si -- lon 
}
```

[image: music notation, Lilypond output]